# Show / Hide multiple DIVs with Select using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dropdown

I essentially have the same situation as a lot of other people.

Through extensive searching within Google I was able to come up with several different methods in which people claim their method works. I have yet to get any to work correctly yet. I don't yet know enough about jQuery to fully understand how to write this from scratch, thus I rely on really good examples for now.

What I've been trying to work with (based on examples I've found and tried) is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        ('.box').hide();
        ('#dropdown').change(function() {
        ('#divarea1')[ ($(this).val() == 'area1') ? 'hide' : 'show' ]()
        ('#divarea2')[ ($(this).val() == 'area2') ? 'hide' : 'show' ]()
        ('#divarea3')[ ($(this).val() == 'area3') ? 'hide' : 'show' ]()
        });
    });
</script>
<form>
    <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
        <option value="0">Choose</option>
        <option value="area1">DIV Area 1</option>
        <option value="area2">DIV Area 2</option>
        <option value="area3">DIV Area 3</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div id="divarea1" class="box">DIV Area 1</div>
<div id="divarea2" class="box">DIV Area 2</div>
<div id="divarea3" class="box">DIV Area 3</div>
```

Note: I am using brackets rather than the less-than and greater-than signs around html to display correctly in this message.
What I get when I test this:

On first load with nothing selected => No DIV is display.

When I select DIV Area 1 => DIV Area 2 and 3 are displayed.

When I select DIV Area 2 => DIV Area 1 and 3 are displayed.

When I select DIV Area 3 => DIV Area 1 and 2 are displayed.

My brain is fried for the day. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Do you have a <br/> in your jquery script? its shown in question you posted !!

Comment: You're also missing the `$` variable to reference jQuery itself

Comment: what is your question exactly? `toggle()` can toggle the visibility

Comment: That's a mistake i made by posting the question. I tried everything and am a little bit of a newbie in jquery.

Comment: My question is: how can i show different DIVS depending on de selection in the dropdown. This is what i want to achieve: 
On first load with nothing selected => No DIV is display.

When I select DIV Area 1 => DIV Area 2 and 3 are displayed.

When I select DIV Area 2 => DIV Area 1 and 3 are displayed.

When I select DIV Area 3 => DIV Area 1 and 2 are displayed.

Comment: Remove <br> from your code, use $ with jQuery and don't forget to use semi colon at the end of the directive lines: https://jsfiddle.net/fLb6xfbq/4/ It's also recommended to make it dynamic as the answer shows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you're missing the `$` reference to jQuery in the JS code. I'm going to assume that's just a typo in the question.

The simplest way to achieve this is to `show()` all the divs on change of the select, then use the chosen value to hide the relevant single `div` based on its `id`. Something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dropdown').change(function() {
    $('.box').show().filter('#div' + $(this).val()).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
    <option value="0">Choose</option>
    <option value="area1">DIV Area 1</option>
    <option value="area2">DIV Area 2</option>
    <option value="area3">DIV Area 3</option>
  </select>
</form>
<div id="divarea1" class="box">DIV Area 1</div>
<div id="divarea2" class="box">DIV Area 2</div>
<div id="divarea3" class="box">DIV Area 3</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The question is a little bit more complicated. I thought by giving a small example it would be easy to apply it to my project. The problem is i have 40 options in the dropdown. Every option will show between 2 / 10 divs depending on the chosen option. So what i want is HIDE ALL on selection and only show the divs which need to be visible by that selection.

Comment: In that case I would start a new question which has a more accurate outline of your requirements

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `$` reference.

I tried your code in `JsFiddle` with  `$`, it works fine

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.box').hide();        
    });
//just tried to move it out of document. ready. But it makes no difference
$('#dropdown').change(function() {        
    $('#divarea1')[ ($(this).val() == "area1") ? 'hide' : 'show' ]();
    $('#divarea2')[ ($(this).val() == "area2") ? 'hide' : 'show' ]();
    $('#divarea3')[ ($(this).val() == "area3") ? 'hide' : 'show' ]();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

as others noted, you missed a `$`.

BASED on your comment above: *`On first load with nothing selected => No DIV is displayed. When I select DIV Area 1 => DIV Area 2 and 3 are displayed. When I select DIV Area 2 => DIV Area 1 and 3 are displayed. When I select DIV Area 3 => DIV Area 1 and 2 are displayed`*

**If you want to show the other DIVs and NOT the one selected... you can use this code:**

```
$(function() {

    $('.box').hide();
        $('#dropdown').change(function() {
          var v = $(this).val();
                $('.box').hide();
                $(".box:not(#div"+v+")").show();           

        });


        });
```

See FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/dwn2bwhn/19/